# Subject and body don't show up after adding mailto intent in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mailto

I have made a basic app (using Java) that emails an order summary to the user. On running the app, it opens up Gmail when an order is made, but the subject and body field of the email remain empty even though I have specified them in the intent. There is no error anywhere. How do I solve this?

```
// This method is called when the order button is clicked.
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    CheckBox checkWhippedCream = findViewById(R.id.whippedcream);
    boolean hasWhippedCream = checkWhippedCream.isChecked();

    CheckBox checkChocolate = findViewById(R.id.chocolate);
    boolean hasChocolate = checkChocolate.isChecked();

    EditText nameField = findViewById(R.id.naam);
    String name = name.getText().toString();

    int price = calculatePrice(hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate);    

    // The order summary will be formed. 
    String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream, hasChocolate, name);
    displayMessage(priceMessage);        //  displayMessage will display the order summary in the app.

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: "));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "CoffeeShoppee Order for " + name);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple implementation worked for me :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:badreddine@bou-devlpr.xyz"));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback/Report");
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: subject field won't get auto filled in gmail app.